# To recursively show all the files in the current folder (= flat view)

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I want to have a quick and easy way to view all the files in a current folder, the so-called "flat view".

I see two possible ways for this, but none of them really works for me yet.

The first is to use the search field in the top right corner. It seems earlier macOS versions supported

```
-kind:folder
```

search criteria, but this doesn't seem to work anymore, at least on my Ventura 13.5.

The second approach, which I think would be even better, is to have a saved search in the Finder sidebar. You can create it using the following steps:

1. Open Finder, click **File** > **New Smart Folder**
2. Click the plus sign next to the **Save** button
3. Hold the **Option** key so that the second plus sign will be changed to the ellipsis, and click it.
4. Adjust the rest as follows:

   > [image]

The second approach works, but I don't understand how to make it work for the **current** folder, that is, any folder I'm currently in. Is it possible? Or what are good alternatives?

(FWIW, I'm not sure I really want to **not** show folders in flat view. So if you have a solution or idea that works, but there is one single disadvantage that it doesn't hide folders, this might be nevertheless exactly what I'm looking for.)

Comment: Maybe we can work on what your ultimate goal is because recursion means going into each *child* folder up to and including the current folder.  You make no mention of this, you just reference "current folder."  Then you have a smart folder filter that it's not clear where you're trying to take it.  Can you give an example of what you're trying to find wiithout the "technicals" added in?

Comment: You can nearly get what you want, but have to accept it also lists the sub folders, by just entering a search of `-` and then selecting the current folder. It's a compromise, but the only other way I know of doing it is by not using Finder, but a 'replacement' Finder called Leap https://ironicsoftware.com/leap/ I used it a lot in 10.9 to 10.12 days, but couldn't justify the upgrade cost when I got into Monterey & beyond. Therein is the warning, Leap ain't cheap.

Comment: Even entering `-` seems to return an incomplete result, not sure what the circumstances are, so YMMV. Take my comment above with a large pinch.

Comment: Like @AndyGriffiths I would go for a 3rd party tool. HoudahSpot is my choice. Somewhat cheaper than Leap.

Comment: In the parent folder that contains the 12 child folders, just use the search term `kind:pdf` to get what you're looking for.  If you want to do this by name, use `name:foo.bar`. That will give you all 48 files while excluding the folders themselves.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Allan For example, I have a folder "Reports", and there are 12 folders there, "January", "February", etc. Each of these 12 folders contains 4 PDFs: "1st-week.pdf", "2nd-week.pdf", etc. I want to double-click the "Reports" folder to open it and then get access (by clicking some "magic button" at the Finder's sidebar, for example) to all the 48 files from its 12 subfolders without opening them (by "them" I mean subfolders). // (This is a *copy* of my comment to which Allan have answered above.)

Comment: since you edited your comment after I posted mine, can you let me know if what I proposed worked or is at least on the right path?

Comment: @Allan But what if there are files of multiple formats in these 12 folders, not only `.pdf`, but also `.txt`, `.jpg` and so on, and I don't even know which ones. I just want to see **all** of them. // There are no significant changes in the comment I have edited and posted after your answer. Just grammar, punctuation, and so on.

Comment: No problem, we can search by name.  In the search (Spotlight), you can type `Name:-week` and it will automatically search for all files that contains that phrse. 
 Same with a smart folder; the first field should be `Name`, then the second field should be `contains` and then enter `-week`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I have found that `-kind:folder` is not accepted in Finder's search box for macOS 13. But these are accepted in Finder's search box:

`NOT(kind:folder)`, `NOT (kind:folder)`, or `NOT kind:folder`

Try that.

The Apple Support page [Narrow your search results on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh15155/mac) refers to the use of AND, OR and NOT. It also clarifies the use of `-`, which means `AND NOT` as in `trip -france`.

I don't have a link to a more formal reference page.

Comment: And as I have realized now, if one day this solution won't work anymore for some reason, we can simply use a period (`.`), because most **file** names have it and most **folder** names don't. Just a quick-and-dirty workaround.

Comment: @jsx97 I love `name:.`! I will add a link to the Apple support page.

Comment: "Apple support page" - Could you give a link?

Comment: @jsx97 The . issue might be true on other Unixes but for macOS not so truue each app and often files used by an app is a bundle which is a directory - Finder might see apps and som bundles as one thing but not all bundles.

Comment: Gilby, maybe you know how to make your solution work to show not just files, but both files and folders? I have tried `kind:ANY`, but this doesn't seem to work. As a workaround, we can negatively search for a non-existent file type, like `NOT kind:abcxyz`, but I would prefer to find a "real" way of doing this, not a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you mean, but from List View, Opt/clicking any folder will auto-expand its entire hierarchy. This, of course, still shows folders in their correct places, but expands to reveal all contents.

Example - first just clicked, then opt/clicked.

[image]

Comment: This is another way, thanks. I'm not really like List View itself, but yes, Opt-click do what I asked for